# Try to compare keys in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I need to loop into this array and compare the value of the object that is in the array but I have try different methods and I can get it. am i missing something or is there a better way to do it?

```
var all = [{a: 1, b: 2, c: 9, d: 5}, {a: 1, t: 58, r: 19, d: 5}, {a: 1, t: 14, r: 89, d: 5}];

for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
 for (var j = 0; j < all.length; j++) {
  for(var key in i){
   for(var keyz in j){
        if(all[i][key] != all[j][keyz]){
        console.log('no same');
        }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Since when is "i" an object?

Comment: So if it is an index (see a number) - what does the `for(var key in i){` statement mean?

Comment: so what is the output you want from here?

Comment: I'm using this to console log the word same but at the end I want to delete the ones that are the same so that i get something like 
`var all = [{b: 2, c: 9}, {t: 58, r: 19}, {t: 14, r: 89}];`

Comment: @ReySomething you want to delete same property name with the same value correct?

Comment: @AivanMonceller yes thats is my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var all = [{a: 1, b: 2, c: 9, d: 5}, {a: 1, t: 58, r: 19, d: 5}, {a: 1, t: 14, r: 89, d: 5}];
    var output = [], tempObj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
        var object =  all[i];
        for(var key in object) {
            if(tempObj[key] && tempObj[key].value == object[key]) {
                delete output[tempObj[key].index][key];
                delete object[key];
            } else {
                tempObj[key] = {
                    value: object[key],
                    index: i
                }
            }
        }
        output[i] = object;
    }
    console.log(output)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < all.length; j++) { 
        for (var key in all[i]) {
            if (typeof all[j][key] !== "undefined" && all[i][key] == all[j][key] && i != j) {
                 console.log("same");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its there a short way to to this and get the same result ?

Comment: @ReySomething define "short".

Comment: @downvoter: Please at least comment what your problem is

Comment: @ReySomething define "efficient".

Comment: @zerkms I fount methods like .filter() or .map() that work whit arrays just wondering if there is other way to do it.

Comment: @ReySomething any technical reason to find "the other way"? Is anything wrong with the provided solution?

Comment: @zerkms no the solution its good just like to know because I'm learning javascrip

Comment: @Balint Thank you very much.